# can I speed-up my application building boost myself (optimizing to target platform)?

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I'm developing HFT trading application which supposed to run on one machine only. So when compile I add `-march=native -mtune=native` flags

But boost is installed from repository: `yum install boost` and `yum install boost-devel`

What if I download boost sources and compile them myself on the target PC with `-march=native -mtune=native` enabled flags. Will this speed-up my application? Will it be signifficant performance improvement? If it worth it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically. Yes. But since boost is highly generic, the chances of this being significant are really slim.

In my experience the only thing that requires prebuilt libraries have to do with lots of static data (UNICODE, localization) and non-generic facilities that don't need performance

Comment: how can I tell boost to use `-march=native -mtune=native` when building? currently i just execute `./bootstrap.sh` and `./b2 install`

Comment: Use [toolset config](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/configuration.html) (_"All of Boost.Build's standard compiler toolsets accept four options cflags, cxxflags, compileflags and linkflags as options specifying flags that will be always passed to the corresponding tools"_), or pass them as [properties on the command line](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html#bbv2.overview.invocation.properties).

Comment: i just wonder if I first person who trying to compile boost optimized to target platform. Isn't boost something that supposed to be run only on computer it compiled? If so why it is not compiling to target platform by default? Why this is not explicitly suggested in docs?

Comment: I think it's sort of assumed you know that to optimize you have to pass the relevant options. In my opinion this is more than hinted at in a dozen "install/build" documentation pages. It's not really a good idea to default to the local machine as it would not run on any other machine in the deployed landscape. Then again. Install gentoo. The OS where your expectations are met

Comment: do you know how can I pass `cxxflags=-O3 -march=native -mtune=native` in command line? should I add quotes like this? `cxxflags="-O3 -march=native -mtune=native"` ?

Comment: I suggest you try it. I expect you to find out very very fast. (Of course, assuming a shell, most would require the latter).

Comment: i still wonder what exact options and where should I pass to ensure I compiled boost for the best performance on target platform. `-march=native -mtune=native` is just my guess, probably I should do something else

Comment: I have no clue what you expect to find. Should I tell you about the secret, magical `--silver-bullet=42` option? (Oh, that, obviously makes Boost 42x as fast regardless of the system)

Comment: right something like that. i need secret option that optimize boost most to target platform while compiling. (in C#/Java JIT optimize byte-code to target platform, in c++ we have to do this during compilation). I wonder this is not default option because in my opinion it's very rare case that someone compile boost and then copy-paste it to another machine.

Comment: @javapowered You can feel free to adjust your opinion to reality as it presents itself to you any moment :) And you can keep plinking me to tell me how surprised you are, but it's a bit like looking at Mona Lisa over and over to see whether she really doesn't wear any make up yet. You'll have to put it on.

Comment: Like I said, use Gentoo or something which can take arbitrary CFLAGS even when compiling your kernel. To me it sounds like you're wasting time not implementing your performance requirements, instead praying to the performance gods to give you magical performance in exchange for a virgin sacrifice. Go. Measure the performance gain when you build Boost with these flags. I expect the gains to be less than exciting, and nothing at all for the vast majority of applications. My answer already explains why I expect this to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

In general: If you have performance issues in your application, try to find out where the problem is exactly. For that enable performance analyzes with your toolchain.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/gprof-tutorial/

To your question: Boost is mostly template stuff which is always compiled while included in your application. Before searching inside library stuff I would check with grpof where your performance really lack is. I *think* that enabling some optimization flags while compiling the boost libs will have not much effect. But why you don't try it?

Answer (score 0):

In HFT time really counts. so have your design reviewed by the best professionals you can get. have your code reviewed by the best professionals you can get. switch to a state of the art compiler and use move semantics. design for concurrency to reduce latency. and profile, profile, profile. in my nice little real time world at some point you are fast enough and done. you will probably be in a constant struggle for microseconds.